# Ubuntu OS CD has a price

Tags: software-installation

Is there a difference in Ubuntu OS when I buy it on Amazon and the free version available in Ubuntu official site?

Comment: You need to ask the seller how exactly the CDs were produced.

Comment: You need to ask amazon.

Comment: They might have been charging for the medium and shipping. There should be no difference if that is an Ubuntu CD. Do you have the link?

Comment: @Rinzwind that'w why I wanted the link to see what they were doing there

Answer (score 8):

No. If they created it using the official installer, there should be almost no difference between an installation CD that someone charges you for and any other installation CD.